# GRUB having problems with my sda1 UUID

Tags: boot, grub, uuid

I was having trouble trying to setup triple boot on my computer... (Take a look at [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/57511/triple-boot-problem-xp-x-seven-x-ubuntu) if you think it would help).
I ended up by having a GRUB menu that has Ubuntu entries and "Windows" entry, that calls an EasyBCD menu to choose between Windows 7 and XP.

Everything would be fine if, only **if**, GRUB was set up correctly.

I can't find why, but it throws me this when I try to open Ubuntu:

[image]

I've already tried to remove the menu.lst and do a grub-update, and a grub-install too.
I tried to create a symlink to /dev/sda1 at /dev/disk/by-uuid/<<uuid that is there>>, just like the other UUIDs that were there... But I couldn't find that symlink at that busybox that opened when it thrown me the error.

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**
This is the GRUB entry with problems:

> title           Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-15-generic
>   uuid            b1ed36e5-4d84-4eb8-86ef-6f1135ffc238
>   kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-15-generic root=UUID=b1ed36e5-4d84-4eb8-86ef-6f1135ffc238 ro quiet splash
>   initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-15-generic
>   quiet

And this my `/dev/disk/by-uuid` folder:

> 04DCBCFBDCBCE856 -> ../../sdb1 (NTFS backup disk)
>   4434E77734E769FE -> ../../sda4 (NTFS WinXP)
>   ACB09F0DB09EDCE0 -> ../../sda2 (NTFS Win7)
>   b5311be8-a853-4fdd-aed5-d65974b3c0c4 -> ../../sda5 (EXT4 home)
>   C04B-4D97 -> ../../sdc (FAT32 live-pendrive from which i'm running)
>   D28447F68447DB9B -> ../../sda6 (NTFS files partition)
>   e0e88f38-d815-423a-9d5e-64b9c74a8b92 -> ../../sda7 (swap)

Comment: can you post the relevant entry of your /boot/grub/menu.lst?  in particular it will help to see the `kernel` line.  (maybe just post the output of this command: `grep kernel /boot/grub/menu.lst`)

Comment: or if you can't get to it, write down what you can see on the `kernel` line from within Grub at boot-time.  it's likely the `root=` parameter is broken.

Comment: Added what you asked and the by-uuid. xD

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry, I totally lost track of this question.  Did you ever get it worked out?

According to the */dev/disk/by-uuid* listing, there *isn't* a UUID associated with */dev/sda1*.  Are you sure it's still a valid root partition?

- You should be able to check with the command `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`.  If that works,
- try running *fsck* on it (start with `sudo fsck -n /dev/sda1` to see if it reports any errors), and if that works
- try mounting the filesystem (`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` or similar).

If those three tests work, maybe the problem is that something accidentally unset the filesystem's UUID.  You can try resetting the UUID to its old value with this:

```
sudo tune2fs -U b1ed36e5-4d84-4eb8-86ef-6f1135ffc238 /dev/sda1
```

If one of the filesystem tests fails, you may have another problem on your hands, but there are too many possibilities to go into without further info.

Answer (score 0):

Only need reinstall grub2 and uninstall grub and these kernels which aren't refresh. This is good for me.